# How to apply PTransform to PCollection conditionnaly?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

**I have a `PCollection` and want to apply a custom `PTransform` if a condition is verified.** (That condition doesn't depends on the `Pcollection`content)
*Example :* I have logs, and if a date is provided in `PipelineOptions`, I want to filter on that date.

Right now, the best solution I have is :

```java
// Read File
PCollection<LogRow> logs = p.apply("LoadData", TextIO.read().from(options.getInput()))
if(!date.equals("")){
    logs = logs.apply("FilterOnDate", ParDo.of(new DateFilterFn(date)));
}
logs = logs.apply(...
```

It works but I don't like to reassign logs. Even more, I don't like to break the chain of `apply`. It doesn't look like the elegant way to do it.

Is there some kind of Conditional `PTransform` ? Or if there isn't, would it be more efficient to put the condition check inside the `PTransform` and to output everything if not verified ?

*Dream example :*

```java
PCollection<LogRow> logs = p.apply("LoadData", TextIO.read().from(options.getInput()))
    .applyIf("FilterOnDate", ParDo.of(new DateFilterFn(date)), !date.equals(""))
    .apply(...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Beam does not have any similar to `applyIf`,
Your current approach is the general way to do such kind of conditional filtering.

Conditional check within the PTransform adds an extra operation for every element which will have an impact of the performance based on the type of check.

If possible, its better to avoid the transform from the pipeline instead of making the PTransform more complex.

From code aesthetic point of view, you can use wrapper transform to conditinally apply the relevant filter pardo.
Example:

```
public static class ConditionallyFilter
      extends PTransform<PCollection<LogRow>, PCollection<LogRow>> {
  private final String date;
  public ConditionallyFilter(String date){
    this.date = date;
  }
  @Override
  public PCollection<LogRow> expand(PCollection<LogRow> logs) {
    if(!date.equals("")){
      logs = logs.apply("FilterOnDate", ParDo.of(new DateFilterFn(date)));
    }
    return logs;
  }
} 


// Read File
PCollection<LogRow> logs = p.apply("LoadData", TextIO.read().from(options.getInput())).apply(new ConditionallyFilter(date)).apply(...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree with you on the performance aspect. I also like the use of a wrapper ! I'll go with it for now. Cheers !